# Build a payments system using Stellar

Tags: payments

I would like to know how I can make payment transactions, receive and buy / sell lumens with the stellar system. I do not encounter any indication to do all this, I have a business and I am interested in using it

Answer (score 1):

The official resources can help you get a broad overview and ask more targeted questions. https://www.stellar.org/how-it-works/stellar-basics/

This walkthrough may also help: https://blog.abuiles.com/building-your-own-venmo-with-stellar/#building-your-own-venmo-with-stellar